# With AngularJs + Web API, why we need ASP.NET MVC and IIS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs, iis, asp.net-web-api

With AngularJs + Web API, why we need ASP.NET MVC and IIS?

Can I just use AngularJS plus WEB API to develop a web application without IIS and ASP.NET MVC ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> With AngularJs + Web API, why we need ASP.NET MVC and IIS?

By off-loading all the logic onto the client without providing a server side fallback, you cause the site to break [when the JS doesn't load](http://digital.cabinetoffice.gov.uk/2013/10/21/how-many-people-are-missing-out-on-javascript-enhancement/), including for search engine indexing bots.

> Can I just use AngularJS plus WEB API to develop a web application without IIS and ASP.NET MVC ?

Yes, it will just be fragile and invisible to search engines.

Comment: Why would search engines care where Web API is hosted?

Comment: Search engines will evolve. ;)    I bet Google (the creators of AngularJS) have certainly began building Chromium/V8 into their search engine's site indexing capabilities.

Answer (score 3):

It is definitely possible from the technology point view. I see 2 areas of concern:

1. Would clients with outdated browsers have problems accessing the site? This is less of a problem as new versions of browsers are getting released.
2. Are the non-IIS hosted hosted Web API services robust and scalable enough?

Comment: Thanks and the Web API services are good enough to handle the loads. I am not sure if using AngularJs as web server is a good solution.