# how to render angular application in asp.net mvc application with out iframe?

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-mvc, plugins, jquery-plugins

i would like to know if we can show an **angular component** inside a **div** of **another application** which can be asp.net MVC so that this feels like one single application.

One way i found is to show the angular application inside an iframe but this will have many limitation in our case like the loader will only be shown inside the i frame.

like can we create java script plugin which can be used in the other application?

Comment: Iframes should not be the solution,  you can use JavaScript in any view in your mvc application

Comment: but how to have an angular application in MVC

Comment: http://www.developerin.net/a/53-Programming/123-Integrate-Angular-with-ASP.NET-MVC
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097592/mixing-angular-and-asp-net-mvc-web-api

Comment: @Vince do you have any information on how to configure webpack in an angular 10 application